# What is the difference between iOS Developer Program and iOS Developer Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, development, app-store-connect

Can I, as a single person, sell my apps with the normal iOS Developer Program ? What is the difference between these two ? 
I have the link here, I just don't understand what really differs between these two... http://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/

Answer (score 3):

As a single person you are eligible to sell apps when enrolled in "iOS Developer Program - Individual".

> For an individual developer who will be creating free and **commercial** iOS apps for distribution on the App Store.

If you want to enroll in the Enterprise Program, you must be company with a **DUNS number**.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the Enterprise program is for companies who wish to develop their own application for use within their own business, but who will not distribute those application commercially on the App Store, in fact they are not allowed to sell on the App Store.